# Сравнение элементов списков разной длины

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть один список длиной в 10 элементов и список списков, каждый длиной в 5 элементов.

```py
mixed = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
list_min = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5], [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
list_max = [[3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [4.5, 6.5, 8.5, 10.5, 12.5], [5.5, 7.5, 9.5, 11.5, 13.5]]
```

Мне нужно, чтобы каждый элемент списка `mixed` сравнился с каждым элементом из каждого списка, двух списков `list_min` и `list_max`. И если он попадает между какими-то элементами, выталкивать его в отельный список.

То есть, берём `mixed[0]` и сравниваем с `list_min[0][0]` и `list_max[0][0]` он попадает между ними - вытолкнули его из списка в список `list0`. 
Дальше, элемент `mixed[1]` (кстати, тут тоже небольшая заминка, если мы вытолкнем элемент, нужно будет вернуться к прежнему индексу), также сравниваем с `list_min[0][0]` и `list_max[0][0]` - между ними не попадаем, идём дальше и сравниваем с с `list_min[0][1]` и `list_max[0][1]` - попадает, выталкиваем. Так, поочерёдно пройтись по всем спискам. Мне нужно, чтобы в `mixed` остались только те элементы, которые не попадают в "граничные" списки. Как я понимаю, цикл должен быть длиной со список `mixed`,

В итоге должны получиться три списка: `list0`, `list1`, `list2`. Чтобы в первом списке были элементы которые попали между списками `list_min[0]` и `list_max[0]`, во втором между `list_min[1]` и `list_max[1]`. И список с остатками `mixed`, которые не влезли в границы хоть какого-то из списков.

P.s. Пример из головы, реальные данные списков смешаны неравномерно, они не идут в порядке возрастания и в них нет закономерности чётные/нечётные. Пример приведён для лучшего понимания задачи. Единственное что, каждый список из списка списков - одной длины и элементы списка из `list_min[i]`, меньше чем элементы из списка `list_max[i]`. Т.е. в данном случае каждый из списков `list_min`, `list_max` состоит из 3 списков, длиной в 5 элементов. Выталкивание должно строиться по первому совпадению. Если элемент попал между элементами первых списков, вытолкнуть его и по остальным спискам не проходиться.

P.p.s. Чёткий ответ (или конкретный код) не требуется, достаточно намекнуть как правильно цикл построить. Я вроде понимаю, что будут вложенные циклы, с тремя уровнями вложенности (по длине `list_min`, `list_min[i]` и `mixed`), но до меня не доходит в каком порядке по ним проходиться. Сейчас мне просто выдаёт ошибку вылета за пределы списков.

> IndexError: list index out of range

---

Upd. В связи с ответом @MBo на вопрос, стоит уточнить задачу. В конечном итоге мне нужно будет работать со списком `mixed` в котором находятся объекты класса (например, `Class1`). У этого класса есть характеристики (пусть будут `time`, `r` и `epsilon`). Из него я образовала соответствующие списки: `mixed_time`, `mixed _r` и `mixed_epsilon`. То есть один элемент (объект) из списка `mixed` (допустим `mixed[3]`), это элемент-объект из которого берутся значения для элементов списков `mixed_time[3]`, `mixed _r[3]` и `mixed_epsilon[3]`. Я веду к тому, что сортировать их нельзя, иначе они не будут соответствовать характеристикам объектов из изначального списка `mixed`. Вполне возможно, что мне не стоило раскладывать изначальный список на списки по конкретным  характеристикам. Весь смысл в том, что в итоге, мне нужно будет сравнить характеристики объекта одного из классов, с характеристиками объекта из другого класса (классы разные, характеристики одни и те же).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmp_lst = list(zip([x for y in list_min for x in y], [x for y in list_max for x in y]))

indices = []
for i in range(len(mixed)):
    for j in range(len(cmp_lst)):
        if (mixed[i] < cmp_lst[j][1]) and (mixed[i] > cmp_lst[j][0]):
            indices.append(i)

[mixed.pop(x) for x in sorted(set(indices), reverse=True)]
print(mixed)
```

Результат:

```
[14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы обойти список с удалением элементов, можно выполнить обход **от конца к началу** (есть также вариант с while).

`они не идут в порядке возрастания` - а сортировка данных также была бы полезной - это позволит быстрее искать место для вставки.

Answer (score 1):

Получается вот такая светомузыка:

```
# Этот класс (label) нужен, чтобы выскочить из внутреннего цикла
class label(Exception): pass

mixed = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
list_min = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5], [4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
list_max = [[3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [4.5, 6.5, 8.5, 10.5, 12.5], [5.5, 7.5, 9.5, 11.5, 13.5]]

# Результирующий массив
res = []

# Идем с конца
for i in range(len(mixed)-1, -1, -1):
    # заключаем все в try except, чтобы выскочить из внутреннего цикла
    try:
        # помещаем очередной элемент в v (первым будет 20)
        v = mixed[i]
        # Берем длину одного из списка списков, в данном случае list_min
        # подразумевая, что списки списков (мин и макс) по длине одинаковые
        for list_index in range(len(list_min)):
            # получаем очередные списки из списков
            mins = list_min[list_index]
            maxs = list_max[list_index]

            # бежим по внутренним спискам, подразумевая, что mins и maxs
            # имеют одинаковые размеры
            for v_idx in range(len(mins)):
                print('min={} v={} max={}'.format(mins[v_idx], v, maxs[v_idx]))

                if v > mins[v_idx] and v < maxs[v_idx]:
                    # вынимаем
                    mixed.pop(i)
                    # помещаем
                    res.append(v)
                    # улетаем  н̶а̶ ̶ю̶г̶  в except
                    raise label

    except label:
        continue

# Выводим результат    
print(res)
```